# Node content will not display only on homepage

Tags: drupal-7

I have some content for the front page of my site, but it will not display in the "Content" block region for my theme.  All other pages display their node content fine.  I have looked at the following to diagnose:

1) Moved the "Main Page Content" block to other regions to see if it will display anywhere at all. It does.

2) Checked permissions. My user is an admin, and admin has all permissions.

3) Altered other pages content to see if it changes.  It does, it only seems to affect the front page.

4) When I make other pages the sites home page, it's content also disappears.  Example: When I make the "About Us" page the sites home page, the content at '/' (supposed to be the About Us content node) is gone, and it also is gone from '/about-us'.  Meanwhile, the page I have been trying to make my homepage previously, displays fine.  So this problem only affects pages that have been made the home page.

5) There is not any sort of "Show block on specific pages" or otherwise, that would conditionally hide it.

All the other blocks in the "Main Page Content" region on the home page display fine. Clearing cache does not do anything.  There are no panel node template overrides.  I am really baffled.  Googled for this, and no love.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have own template for frontpage? like page--front.tpl.php etc?

Comment: Nope, there is nothing like that in the theme.

Comment: What kind of node content exactly you have in that block in frontpage? Just page with same url as front?

Comment: Just the standard body field of a Basic Page.

Comment: In some themes there is option to hide content in homepage.. check that from theme settings..

Answer (score 0):

Please verify do you have following code on your theme?

```
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

Comment: Yes, it's there.  There do not seem to be any "if" conditions around it that would preclude it showing up on the front, or any other page.